# Adding a new section in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, web, web-deployment, mathjax

I want to add a section in my website. I am using word-press. The section will be named "Questions and answers". The site I have created has two section only named, **"Home"** and **"sample page"**.  A new section will be then **"Questions and answers"**. In the new section people will ask question and answer. Moreover I want to add latex environment there. What to do .Please help.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_section

Comment: Hey Forhad is asking about fron-end not admin-end.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Just create a template (if you know) and in that template write the

shortcode of "CM Answers" plugin. Of course you will download "CM Answers" plugin by follwing

this link:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/cm-answers/

You can customize all thing in it. It will work just like stackoverflow .com site.

Try it.

Comment: Great. Will it support latex or, I will have to install  mathjax  ?

Comment: Sorry, But it will not support latex. Use your own mathjax or "latex plugin" by visiting this link: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-latex/

Comment: So I will have to install latex to my site then the CM answer will  convert the latex equation to images.  

But the problem s , I have installed the CM answer plug in . But it is not showing in the website views. What more need to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "But it is not showing in the website views"? Firstly read all documentation of "CM Plugin" and do not hurry.

Comment: I meant after installation the plug in in word-press, how to add that in my website so people can view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Q&A plugin to get this functionality. More about it [here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin/)